# Android Fragments amount

Tags: android, fragment

I am designing an app based around having a large amount of fragments containing information.

I was just wondering (since I plan on upwards of 100+ fragments). If there is an easier way/less cluttered way to do this?

I have 3 at the moment and that means I have 3 different fragment classes, as well as 3 different fragment layouts?

I am very inexperienced with fragments so I am not sure which direction is best.

Comment: Are all your fragments sharing any similar structure?

Comment: Yes I want every single fragment to share the exact same structure. The only difference will obviously be different text and images inside them.

Comment: Then you need only 1 fragment I would say. All you need to do is to update the view(s) in your fragment should there be a changed in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want every single fragment to share the exact same structure. The only difference will obviously be different text and images inside them

Then you should not have 100+ fragment *classes*, or even 3 fragment classes. You should have one fragment class, with its associated layout(s). You are welcome to have many *instances* of that class, with "different text and images inside them".

Comment: May I ask how is it possible to do this? I have my fragments set up so they call a new fragment class. Which contains a contentview set to a new fragment layout.

Sorry to be a pain

Comment: @user2618595: You have not indicated where the "different text and images inside them" are coming from. If, so far, you have been hard-coding those in the layouts, hard-code them as part of *creating* the fragment *instance*. For example, you could use the factory pattern and arguments `Bundle` to pass in data, as I do here with 10 instances of an `EditorFragment`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments